# remove the last 256 byte for a output file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a opened file for output. Due to the limitation, my programme always write 256 extra bytes to that file.

Before I shall close the file, I want to remove those 256 extra bytes. And all of them are "0".

How shall I do it easily?

Thank you

Comment: You want to do it in python or some other tool? `dd` is really fast.

Comment: Curious why it's not possible to avoid writing those bytes in the first place.

Comment: Beause of Python limitation. Didn't you know that Python likes to write random data at the end of output? xD, @thundium: better fix your code in first place.

Comment: @gnibbler, it is a long word. Since I can't know the EOF except using the read function. But for my structure, if the a file is read, either "000000" or data read from the file shall be writen into the output file.

So I can only close all input files by
    
    if not data or len(data)<size: 
      data = data.ljust(size,'0')
      mAntFile[antNo].close()

So when I know all file are closed, actually I have writen some extra "0000" to the files. That's why I want to remove those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seek back 256 bytes from the end (using [`file.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek)) and truncate the file (with [`file.truncate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate)). Adding a `file.flush()` is probably prudent:

```
import os

fileobj.flush()  # clear buffers
fileobj.seek(-256, os.SEEK_END)  # 256 bytes from the end
fileobj.truncate()
```

Comment: Tada! faster than dd even

Comment: @falsetru: thanks for the correction; forgot the seek is always forward even with `os.SEEK_END`.

Comment: it telss me undefined variable from import: SEEK_END ?

Comment: @thundium: That message makes no sense. Did you import `os`? Alternatively, you can use the integer `2`, instead.

Comment: aha, it is beacuse I used a test.py to test how to use this new code, however, since I didn't write anything into the file, the pointer is not yet at the end. So "seek" function with argument (-2, 2) not works.

After use fileobj.write("aaacccc"), the seek then works.